# Draw a triangle in 3D space by Matlab

Tags: matlab, plot, 3d

I have these 3 points:

```
A=[30,0,0]; 
B=[0,40,0]; 
C=[0,0,10];
```

How can I draw a triangle which has the 3 nodes by A,B,C in 3 dimensional space?

Comment: I think I could try the command : "patch(A,B,C,'red')"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have these points:

```
A = [30,0,0];
B = [0,40,0];
C = [0,0,10];
```

Then you can use `Plot3d` for your purpose:

```
Plot3d([30,0,0],[0,40,0],[0,0,10])
```

You can also use  `fill3`:

```
fill3(A,B,C)
```

Also you can use `patch`:

```
patch(A,B,C,[0,6]) 
%fourth argument gives a gradient of colors, alternatively you can use 'red' or 'blue'
```

Or as mentioned in the comments, you can use the following:

## [Search](https://www.google.com/search?q=Draw+a+triangle+in+3D+space+by+Matlab&rlz=1C1FLDB_enUS727US727&oq=Draw+a+triangle+in+3D+space+by+Matlab&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60l3&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Comment: These commands are wrong. There is a plot3 and a fill3 with a 4th parameter for color coordinates

Comment: @blueether I don't follow. I am using `fill3`, but not using the 4th optional parameter. OP didn't ask for a specific color, so would you clarify what's wrong?